# Unable to increase the value of multiple variables

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch files and have a very simple problem, all I am trying to do is  increase the value of 3 variables by set amounts.

When I run the file, variable 'a' increases as expected but variables 'b' and 'c' return the message "The syntax of the command is incorrect" and echo the original values.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
@set a=0
@set b=10
@set c=100

:1
echo on

echo Value of A = %a% +++++++++++++++++++++++++
echo Value of B = %b% +++++++++++++++++++++++++
echo Value of C = %c% +++++++++++++++++++++++++

set /a a=a+1
set /b b=b+10
set /c c=c+100

goto 1

exit;
```

The following image is from the CMD window showing the batch file output:

[image: CMD window output]

Comment: There is no `set /B` nor `set /C`, you need to state `set /A`; the `/A` portion is a switch telling `set` to do arithmetic operations (type `set /?` in a command prompt window and read the help text); you seem to confuse the switch with your variable names `A`, `B` and `C`...

Comment: All of them should be using `set /a`. You're making the mistake of confusing the variable names with the switch. Voting to close this as off-topic because it's a simple typo. (For future reference, your entire image could have been done as a simple copy/paste of text, which can be done from a command window. Images should only be used when there is no other way to demonstrate the issue. See [this Meta SO post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the reasons why you should avoid using images.)

Comment: Many thanks... comments noted...

Comment: `set /A a+=1, b+=10, c+=100`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your new to batch so I'll be very clear. The set command has to three options:

```
/a = Math
/p = Input
nothing = set
```

Try this:

```
set /a a+=1
set /a b+=10
set /a c+=100
```